# Create a User and Password for ADO.net and SQL SERVER Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to create a sample application  in asp .net mvc with **sql server authentication.**

> I want to create a user with password in sql server so that i can provide it in connection string in asp .net mvc web.config.
>
> My question is how to create a user in sql server 2012 and later login using that user and password,and create databases and tables for my entity framework in .net

What are the steps to create a user and password??

Comment: ,http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/create-a-sql-login-user-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to use SQL Server authentication?

Comment: i was learning how to use it with entity framework in asp .net since the projects that i have worked so far all use it

Comment: Ahh ok. I was going to recommend not using SQL Server authentication since you have to place the username and password in the web.config where as using Windows Authentication you wouldn't have to do that but since just learning, perhaps it doesn't matter.

Comment: But we have used sql server authentication for all the projects that i have worked.does windows authentication work if everyone is accessing data in a server.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through below links :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386610/how-do-i-create-a-new-user-in-sql-server-2012-that-i-can-use-in-a-connection-str

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa337562.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601186/sql-server-script-to-create-a-new-user